# Unsafe pointer/array notation in C#

Tags: c#, pointers

Suppose I have:

```
unsafe {
    byte* start = GetStartLocation();
    int something = start[4];
}
```

What is `something`? The value of the memory address 4 bytes down from start?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say `start` points to memory location 0x12345678, and memory looks like this:

```
  0x12345678   0x12
  0x12345679   0x34
  0x1234567a   0x56
  0x1234567b   0x78
  0x1234567c   0x9a
  0x1234567d   0xbc
```

then `something` equals `0x9a`.

The fact that `something` has type `int` doesn't matter to how `start[4]` is interpreted - it gets the `byte` value of the byte 4 locations away from `start`.

Comment: Thank you! I need to enter 15 characters to post this, which leads me to believe that 'thank you's in general are not allowed, which means this will be deleted shortly, so I hope you see this! Thanks!

Comment: @Sam: Personally, I think the more "thank you"s on SO the better.  Feel free to pad them with smileys as necessary.  8-)

Answer (score 2):

The value of something is the byte value of offset 4 from start widened to an int type.

It's equivalent to the following code

```
byte temp = start[4];
int something = temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

`start[4]` will evaluate to:

```
*(start + 4)
```